# wc -c counting wrong number of characters unix

Tags: awk, sed

That's how my code works, I have been given to count the characters instead of lines because newline characters are gone.

Original file has

```
A,0,0,0,21,36,12,0,0,0,17.2,34,18,17.2,30.5,96,126,517,2399,2,111.83,38.583,111,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

csv file has a bunch of data and I am just counting the number of columns. It just has the same number of columns at the number of commas. I have removed newline characters, so I cannot use wc -l, so I have tried to use wc -c or -m, which returned same value. However, it counted N+1 value.

```
!head -1 ~/where/my/data/is/at.csv | sed 's/[^,]//g' | cat -E

returns [',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,$']
```

When just counting the commas here, it is 30, but when I do `wc -c`, it would return 31.

It should give me 30 for instance, but it's giving me 31. So it's n+1. I want to how to fix such problems, when wc is not counting things right.

Comment: Could you please post sample Input_file and sample expected output in code tags, as it is not clear.

Comment: well in your sample I see only 29 commas, not 30 or 31... if you post sample lines (or create sample lines) and tell what you need as output, it would be more helpful... what could we debug with just output shown? for ex: `printf ',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,' | wc -c` gives 29... what else can one do about it?

Comment: I think awk works very well, but I am just wondering how wc works in a same process as awk does in counting the commas here.

Comment: output of `sed` will have newline character, which is why you get that extra character... try `tr -cd ',' < ip.csv | wc -m`

Comment: Why would you post an example with 30 commas instead of 3???

Comment: sorry should have made it much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're interested in counting the number of columns, you could use **awk** for this:

Using your input:

```
$ cat file
A,0,0,0,21,36,12,0,0,0,17.2,34,18,17.2,30.5,96,126,517,2399,2,111.83,38.583,111,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

gives:

```
$ awk -F, '{print NF}' file
30
```

If you're interested in the number of comma's:

```
$ head -1 file | awk -F, '{print NF-1}'
29
```

BTW, I think you trying to call `wc -m` to count the characters.

Comment: `cat -E`  displays a `$` at the end of each line. Show an extract of your csv to give a more specific answer.

Comment: I understand using awk to find the number of commas, but I actually don't understand why wc -m is giving me N+1 value while awk in fact does a very good job of giving N value that is expected?

Comment: You must be doing something different, because `wc -m` returns `30`. You're sure you're not using `cat -E` somewhere in between?

Comment: I got it, but another question. Can we actually count the number of commas with wc?

Comment: Yes, we can. Look at @SLePort's answer.

Answer (score 4):

`wc -c` will count the newline character added to output after the `cat`.

You can try to pipe `wc -l` to a `grep -o` command which will ouput commas in multiple lines:

```
head -1 ~/where/my/data/is/at.csv | grep -o ',' | wc -l
```